# Задача комивояжера, метод кратчайшего пути

Tags: c++, алгоритм, ооп

есть небольшой вопрос. В моем распоряжении есть выполненная задача Комивоежера методом кратчайшего пути. Мне необходима помощь в одном вопросе. Как я понимаю если алгоритм ищет кратчайший путь, то по факту если этот путь развернуть то получится наибольший. Если это не так поправьте пожалуйста. Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу изменить код так чтобы выводился наибольший путь?

```
#include <GL\glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int n;
int** help;
int* result;
int*** mat;

int WinW;
int WinH;



const int maxSize = 20;
int amountVerts;

template<class T>

class Graph
{
    vector<T> vertList;
    vector<T> labelList;
    bool* visitedVerts = new bool[vertList.size()];
public:
    int adjMatrix[maxSize][maxSize] = { 0 };
    Graph();
    ~Graph();
    void DrawGraph();
    void InsertEdge(const T& vertex1, const T& vertex2, int weight);
    void InsertVertex(const T& vertex);
    void DeleteVertex();
    int GetVertPos(const T& vertex);
    bool IsEmpty();
    bool IsFull();
    int GetAmountVerts();
    int GetAmountEdges();
    int GetWeight(const T& vertex1, const T& vertex2);
    vector<T> GetNbrs(const T& vertex);
    void Print();
};


int R;

struct vertCoord
{
    int x, y;
};
vertCoord vertC[20];

Graph<int> graph;

void answer(int*** mat, int n, int** help, int* path)
{

    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int min = 1000000;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if (mat[i][j] && min > *mat[i][j])
                    min = *mat[i][j];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if (mat[i][j])
                    *mat[i][j] -= min;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            int min = 1000000;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                if (mat[i][j] && min > *mat[i][j])
                    min = *mat[i][j];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                if (mat[i][j])
                    *mat[i][j] -= min;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                help[i][j] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (mat[i][j] && !*mat[i][j])
                {
                    int hmin = 1000000;
                    int vmin = 1000000;

                    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
                        if (l != i && mat[l][j] && hmin > *mat[l][j])
                            hmin = *mat[l][j];

                    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
                        if (l != j && mat[i][l] && vmin > *mat[i][l])
                            vmin = *mat[i][l];

                    help[i][j] = hmin + vmin;
                }
            }

        int mcost = 0, mi = 0, mj = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if (mat[i][j] && mcost < help[i][j])
                {
                    mcost = help[i][j];
                    mi = i;
                    mj = j;
                }
        path[mi] = mj;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            mat[i][mj] = nullptr;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            mat[mi][i] = nullptr;

        mat[mj][mi] = nullptr;
    }
}

void preparation(int***& mat, int& n, int**& help, int*& result)
{
    n = amountVerts;

    help = new int* [n];

    result = new int[n];

    mat = new int** [n];

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        help[i] = new int[n];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = new int* [n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (graph.adjMatrix[i][j] == 0) {
                mat[i][j] = nullptr;
                continue;
            }
            mat[i][j] = new int(graph.adjMatrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}


void tsalesman(int*** mat, int n, int** help, int* result)
{
    preparation(mat, n, help, result);
    int s = 0;
    answer(mat, n, help, result);
    cout << "\nОтрезки путей: ";
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        j = result[i];
        cout << i + 1  << " -> " << j + 1  << '\t';
        s += graph.adjMatrix[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nКратчайший путь: ";
    int temp = 0;
    for (int l = 0; l < n;)
    {
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (temp == 0 || i + 1 == temp)
            {
                if (temp == 0) cout << i + 1;
                j = result[i];
                temp = j + 1;
                if (temp > 0)   cout << " -> " << temp;
                l++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\nРасстояние: " << s;
    cout << endl;
}


template<class T>
std::vector<T> Graph<T>::GetNbrs(const T& vertex) {
    std::vector<T> nbrsList; // создание списка соседей
    int vertPos = this->GetVertPos(vertex); // вычисление позиции vertex в матрице смежности
    if (vertPos != (-1)) {

        for (int i = 0, vertListSize = this->vertList.size(); i < vertListSize; ++i) {
            if (this->adjMatrix[vertPos][i] != 0 &&
                this->adjMatrix[i][vertPos] != 0) // вычисление соседей

                nbrsList.push_back(this->vertList[i]);

        }
    }
    return nbrsList;
}



template<class T>
void Graph<T>::InsertVertex(const T& vertex) {
    if (!this->IsFull()) {
        this->vertList.push_back(vertex);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Граф уже заполнен. Невозможно добавить новую вершину " << endl;
        return;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Graph<T>::DeleteVertex() {

    this->vertList.pop_back();

}


template<class T>
int Graph<T>::GetAmountEdges() {
    int amount = 0; // обнуляем счетчик
    if (!this->IsEmpty()) { // проверяем, что граф не пуст
        for (int i = 0, vertListSize = this->vertList.size();
            i < vertListSize; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vertListSize; ++j) {
                if (this->adjMatrix[i][j] ==
                    this->adjMatrix[j][i] &&
                    this->adjMatrix[i][j] != 0) // находим рёбра
                    amount += 1; // считаем количество рёбер
            }
        }
        return (amount / 2); // приводим счетчик к корректному результату и возвращаем его
    }
    else
        return 0; // если граф пуст, возвращаем 0
}

template<class T>
int Graph<T>::GetWeight(const T& vertex1, const T& vertex2) {
    if (!this->IsEmpty()) {
        int vertPos1 = GetVertPos(vertex1);
        int vertPos2 = GetVertPos(vertex2);
        return adjMatrix[vertPos1][vertPos2];
    }
    return 0;
}

template<class T>
int Graph<T>::GetAmountVerts() {
    return this->vertList.size();
}

template<class T>
bool Graph<T>::IsEmpty() {
    if (this->vertList.size() != 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

template<class T>
bool Graph<T>::IsFull() {
    return (vertList.size() == maxSize);
}

template <class T>
int Graph<T>::GetVertPos(const T& vertex) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->vertList.size(); ++i) {
        if (this->vertList[i] == vertex)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

template<class T>
Graph<T>::Graph() {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxSize; ++j)
        {
            this->adjMatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

template<class T>
Graph<T>::~Graph() {

}


Graph<int> makeGraph()
{
    Graph<int> graph; // создание графа, содержащего вершины с номерами целого типа
    int amountEdges, sourceVertex, targetVertex, edgeWeight; // создание необходимых для ввода графа переменных
    cout << "Введите количество вершин графа: "; cin >> amountVerts; cout << endl; // ввод количества рёбер графа в переменную amountVerts
    cout << "Введите количество ребер графа: "; cin >> amountEdges; cout << endl; // ввод количества рёбер графа в переменную amountEdges
    for (int i = 1; i <= amountVerts; ++i) {
        int* vertPtr = &i; // запоминаем адрес вершины с помощью указателя
        graph.InsertVertex(*vertPtr); //передаём ссылку на вершину в функцию InsertVertex; происходит вставка вершины в вектор вершин
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < amountEdges; ++i) {
        cout << "Исходная вершина: "; cin >> sourceVertex; cout << endl; // ввод исходной вершины
        int* sourceVertPtr = &sourceVertex; // запоминаем адрес исходной вершины
        cout << "Конечная вершина: "; cin >> targetVertex; cout << endl; // ввод вершины, до которой будет идти ребро от исходной вершины
        int* targetVertPtr = &targetVertex; // запоминаем адрес конечной вершины (до которой будет идти ребро от исходной вершины)

        cout << "Вес ребра: "; cin >> edgeWeight; cout << endl; // ввод числового значения веса ребра в переменную edgeWeight
        graph.InsertEdge(*sourceVertPtr, *targetVertPtr, edgeWeight); // вставка ребра весом edgeWeight между исходной и конечной вершинами
    }
    cout << endl;
    return graph;
}

template<class T>
void Graph<T>::InsertEdge(const T& vertex1, const T& vertex2, int weight) {
    if (this->GetVertPos(vertex1) != (-1) && this->GetVertPos(vertex2) != (-1)) {
        int vertPos1 = GetVertPos(vertex1);
        int vertPos2 = GetVertPos(vertex2);
        if (this->adjMatrix[vertPos1][vertPos2] != 0
            && this->adjMatrix[vertPos2][vertPos1] != 0) {
            cout << "Ребро между вершинами уже есть" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else {
            this->adjMatrix[vertPos1][vertPos2] = weight;
            this->adjMatrix[vertPos2][vertPos1] = weight;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Обеих вершин (или одной из них) нет в графе " << endl;
        return;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Graph<T>::Print() {
    if (!this->IsEmpty()) {
        cout << "Матрица смежности графа: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0, vertListSize = this->vertList.size(); i < vertListSize; ++i) {
            cout << this->vertList[i] << " ";
            for (int j = 0; j < vertListSize; ++j) {
                cout << " " << this->adjMatrix[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

    }

}

void setCoord(int i, int n)
{
    int R_;

    int x0 = WinW / 2;
    int y0 = WinH / 2;
    if (WinW > WinH)
    {
        R = 5 * (WinH / 13) / n;
        R_ = WinH / 2 - R - 10;
    }
    else {
        R = 5 * (WinW / 13) / n;
        R_ = WinW / 2 - R - 10;
    }
    float theta = 2.0f * 3.1415926f * float(i) / float(n);
    float y1 = R_ * cos(theta) + y0;
    float x1 = R_ * sin(theta) + x0;

    vertC[i].x = x1;
    vertC[i].y = y1;
}

void drawCircle(int x, int y, int R) //рисуем круг в заданных координатах
{
    glColor3f(0.4, 0.6, 0.0);
    float x1, y1;
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
    {
        float theta = 2.0f * 3.1415926f * float(i) / float(360);
        y1 = R * cos(theta) + y;
        x1 = R * sin(theta) + x;;
        glVertex2f(x1, y1);
    }
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    float x2, y2;
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
    {
        float theta = 2.0f * 3.1415926f * float(i) / float(360);
        y2 = R * cos(theta) + y;
        x2 = R * sin(theta) + x;
        glVertex2f(x2, y2);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void drawText(int nom, int x1, int y1)
{
    GLvoid* font = GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18;
    string s = to_string(nom);
    glRasterPos2i(x1 - 5, y1 - 5);
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, s[j]);
}

void drawVertex(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        drawCircle(vertC[i].x, vertC[i].y, R);
        drawText(i + 1, vertC[i].x, vertC[i].y);
    }
}

void drawLine(int text, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) //ребро неориентированный взвешенный граф
{
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(x0, y0);
    glVertex2i(x1, y1);
    glEnd();

    drawText(text, (x0 + x1) / 2 + 10, (y0 + y1) / 2 + 10);
}


template<class T>
void Graph<T>::DrawGraph()
{
    int n = vertList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        setCoord(i, n);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            int a = adjMatrix[i][j];
            if (a != 0)
            {
                drawLine(a, vertC[i].x, vertC[i].y, vertC[j].x, vertC[j].y);
            }
        }
    }
    drawVertex(n);
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    WinW = w;
    WinH = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)WinW, (GLsizei)WinH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, (GLdouble)WinW, 0, (GLdouble)WinH);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void drawMenuText(string text, int x1, int y1)
{
    GLvoid* font = GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18;
    string s = text;
    glRasterPos2i(x1 + 5, y1 - 20);
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, s[j]);
}

void drawMenu()
{
    int shift = 60;
    int height = 730;

    glColor3d(0.6, 0.2, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2i(0, 0);
    glVertex2i(0, 70);
    glVertex2i(70, 0);

    glEnd();

    glColor3d(0.6, 0.2, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2i(1350, 730);
    glVertex2i(1350, 660);
    glVertex2i(1280, 730);

    glEnd();

    glColor3d(0.6, 0.2, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2i(0, 730);
    glVertex2i(0, 660);
    glVertex2i(70, 730);

    glEnd();

    glColor3d(0.6, 0.2, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2i(1350, 0);
    glVertex2i(1280, 0);
    glVertex2i(1350, 70);

    glEnd();


    glColor3d(0.6, 0.2, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(shift - 10, height - 50);
    glVertex2i(shift + 145, height - 50);
    glVertex2i(shift + 145, height - shift - 200);
    glVertex2i(shift - 10, height - shift - 200);
    glEnd();

    

    

    glColor3d(0, 0.3, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(shift, height - shift - 110);
    glVertex2i(shift + 135, height - shift - 110);
    glVertex2i(shift + 135, height - shift - 80);
    glVertex2i(shift, height - shift - 80);
    glEnd();
    glColor3d(0.8, 1.0, 0.9);
    drawMenuText("Print matrix", shift, height - shift - 82);

    glColor3d(0, 0.3, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(shift, height - shift - 150);
    glVertex2i(shift + 135, height - shift - 150);
    glVertex2i(shift + 135, height - shift - 120);
    glVertex2i(shift, height - shift - 120);
    glEnd();
    glColor3d(0.8, 1.0, 0.9);
    drawMenuText("Answer", shift, height - shift - 122);

    
}

void mouseClick(int btn, int stat, int x, int y) {
    int shift = 60;
    int height = 730;

    if (stat == GLUT_DOWN) {

        if (x > shift && x < shift + 135 && y >  shift && y < shift + 30)
        {
            int sourceVertex;
            int targetVertex;
            int edgeWeight;


            cout << "Исходная вершина: "; cin >> sourceVertex; cout << endl;
            int* sourceVertPtr = &sourceVertex;
            cout << "Конечная вершина: "; cin >> targetVertex; cout << endl;
            int* targetVertPtr = &targetVertex;

            if (sourceVertex > amountVerts || targetVertex > amountVerts) {
                amountVerts++;
                int* vertPtr = &amountVerts;
                graph.InsertVertex(*vertPtr);
            }

            cout << "Вес ребра: "; cin >> edgeWeight; cout << endl;
            graph.InsertEdge(*sourceVertPtr, *targetVertPtr, edgeWeight); // 
        }
        if (x > shift && x < shift + 135 && y > shift + 40 && y < shift + 70)
        {
            int sourceVertex;
            int targetVertex;
            int edgeWeight;

            cout << "Введите вершину: "; cin >> sourceVertex; cout << endl;
            int* sourceVertPtr = &sourceVertex;
            if (sourceVertex == amountVerts)
            {
                amountVerts--;
                graph.DeleteVertex();
            }
            else cout << "Невозможно удалить вершину \n";
        }
        if (x > shift && x < shift + 135 && y >  shift + 80 && y < shift + 100)
        {
            graph.Print();
        }
        if (x > shift && x < shift + 135 && y >  shift + 120 && y < shift + 140)
        {
            tsalesman(mat, n, help, result);
        }
        if (x > shift && x < shift + 135 && y >  shift + 160 && y < shift + 180)
        {
            graph = makeGraph();
        }
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, WinW, 0, WinH); //ставим начало координат в левый нижний угол
    glViewport(0, 0, WinW, WinH);
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.8, 0.4, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    graph.DrawGraph();
    drawMenu();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void visual()
{

}
```

Это код программы.
А вот код предполагаемой части вывода где необходима помощь:

```
void tsalesman(int*** mat, int n, int** help, int* result)
{
    preparation(mat, n, help, result);
    int s = 0;
    answer(mat, n, help, result);
    cout << "\nОтрезки путей: ";
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        j = result[i];
        cout << i + 1  << " -> " << j + 1  << '\t';
        s += graph.adjMatrix[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nКратчайший путь: ";
    int temp = 0;
    for (int l = 0; l < n;)
    {
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (temp == 0 || i + 1 == temp)
            {
                if (temp == 0) cout << i + 1;
                j = result[i];
                temp = j + 1;
                if (temp > 0)   cout << " -> " << temp;
                l++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\nРасстояние: " << s;
    cout << endl;
}
```

По факту необходимо получить алгоритм кратчайшего пути наоборот. Спасибо.

Comment: Как вы думаете если входные данные умножить на -1 а потом результат который вышел из исходного алгоритма снова умножить на -1 то какой будет результат?

Comment: И это не меняя код

Comment: Если у вас есть возможность объяснить немного по подробней с примером, то я буду очень вам благодарен

Comment: да на входе матрица [5, 1] минимальный путь 1. Далее что если умножить на -1 получается матрица [-5, -1] тогда минимальный путь -5 далее умножаем на -1 получаем 5

Comment: Как определяется наибольший путь, что это такое?

Comment: И каким методом, кстати, решена задача коммивояжера?

Comment: Самый длинный маршрут - это не поиск кратчайшего наоборот. Если в сети дорог есть цикл, то самый длинный маршрут получается бесконечным - коммивояжер будет ходить по циклу вечно.

Comment: Задача решена методом ближайшего соседа. И да, спасибо вам, у меня получилось все